# Start Websphere liberty profile in debug mode through Ant

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

Is there any way to start Web Sphere 8.x in debug mode through Ant script?

I see nothing is related to it in the documentation [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_ant_server.html). Just wondering if someone has way arround to do this.

As soon as I start it in debug mode, it display "Listining for transport dt_socket at address: 7777" and then nothing happens afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Server operations available as options: create, start, stop, status, and package.
```

"debug" works as an operation too, just like bin/server debug server-name

Comment: What did you expect from "debug mode"?. It's waiting for you to attach with a java debugger.

Comment: gotcha..I did not know that.